# React Ref get properties after mount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am trying to get elements height after its mounted.
Their height can change according to child element thats why i cant give static height.

```
 const PositionedComponent = styled.div`
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999999999;
      max-height: 300px;
      overflow:unset;
      ${props =>
        !props.hasOverflow && `
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
      `}
    `;
....
          const [elementHeight,setElementHeight] = useState(0);
          const portalRef = useRef(null);
          const childrenContainerRef = useRef(null);
        
          useEffect(()=>{
            if(portalRef.current){
              const portalDimensions = portalRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
              setElementHeight(portalDimensions.height);
            }
          }, [portalRef]);
        ....
        
          return (
            isVisible && (
              <Root>
                {ReactDOM.createPortal(
                  <PositionedComponent
                    ref={portalRef}
                    style={combinedStyles}
                    hasOverflow={hasOverflow}
                    id='positioned-component'
                  >
                    <ChildrenContainer ref={childrenContainerRef}>
                      {children}
                    </ChildrenContainer>
                  </PositionedComponent>,
                  document.getElementById(portalContainerName)
                )}
              </Root>
            )
          );
```

Its not enter useEffect again. Even if it enters useEffect again im not sure i can get the right height.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: If i'm right, you want get height when element was mounted and then update if will change height?

Comment: @ЖнецЪ yes thats correct